# How to get "internal comment field " from quote object

Tags: quote

[image]I have created a Vf page on Quote object .Now how to get "internal comment field " from quote object.
i could see in edit page the internal comment field of an quote object ,but in quote field page the "internal comment " field does not appears.  Any Suggestion plz.

Comment: Is this the OOB Quote object? If yes, share screen shot as I don't see `Internal Comments` as a standard field

Comment: @crop1645:PFA Screen shot of Quote Object .I could see in profile -field permission where the "internal comment " is present with read nd edit option.whereas in "Standard quote object" i could not see the "internal comment" reflecting.

Answer (score 0):

The Standard Description field is labelled as Internal Comments.
Setup - Customize - Rename Tabs and Labels - Select Quotes Tab - Select Next and You could see List of fields and under the Singular Columns see if any of the field is changed to Internal Comments